# flutter command alias for common tasks

Tags: flutter

New to futter, and wonder is there a way to alias scripts similar to `npm/yarn run` in package.json. I want to make it easy to run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` from command line. I could add it to bash/profile alias, but wonder a way to tie it to project file (like pubspec.yaml).

Answer (score 0):

If you're a windows user, then some way is to create a file - eg: "run.bat" and use script like:

```
@ECHO off
IF "%1%"=="build_runner" (
    flutter packages pub run build_runner build
    EXIT 1
)
ECHO "Unknown command."
```

And use it: `.\run.bat build_runner`

If you're a unix user, there's a good article: https://developer.school/quick-tip-speed-up-workflow-with-command-line-aliases/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little overkill for your question but I created a package called [flutter_fast_cli](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fast_cli) that has a few convenient alias commands:

| Command | Runs... |
| --- | --- |
| fast build | dart run build_runner --delete-conflicting-outputs |
| fast clean | flutter clean (with the option to delete the `podspec.lock` file) |

I'm open to adding more too.